# Reusing javax.jms.BytesMessage

Tags: java, jms

I'm working on a heavy load message dispatcher sending out `javax.jms.BytesMessage`.

A single thread is taking application specific objects from a queue, serializing them and sending out as `BytesMessage` (publish to specific topic).

This thread has exactly one JMS session.

Actually a

```java
// for every message
BytesMessage message = session.createBytesMessage();
message.setJMSType("MyType");
message.setStringProperty("MyProp", "val");
message.writeBytes(data);
publisher.send(message);
```

is done for every single message to be sent out.

What about creating only one BytesMessage and reusing them - is this possible/more performant (memory, ...) ?

```java
// only once
session = connection.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
message = session.createBytesMessage();
message.setJMSType("MyType");
message.setStringProperty("MyProp", "val");
```

```java
// for every message
message.clearBody();
message.writeBytes(data);
publisher.send(message);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *is* possible to create a single `BytesMessage` and then just clear it and write new data before each send. However, *how* this will ultimately impact your application from a performance perspective will come down to the JMS client implementation you're using.

Generally speaking you should save a little bit of garbage by reusing the message which means the JVM's garbage collector will have to do less work, but that may not actually be a bottleneck for your application so it may make no real difference ultimately. The bottom line is that you just need to test it to see what difference it makes (if any).

Comment: thanks for comment... i will do some tests